# What is the list on the institutes computer?

Tags: fallout-4

So i have been to the institute and i accessed the terminal. I found a list of names and professions. Among them was Lucas Sims (who i thought was the mayor of megaton in fallout 3), the merchant who goes around selling armor ( i forgot his name but i thought he worked for Stockton), and trashcan Carla. What does this list mean? Are those people working for the institute? I tried killing Carla but she isn't a synth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a list of people who the Institute has been using as informants. They are not synths, they are like Kellogg, who do the Institute's bidding in exchange for money.

I always thought it was suspicious that Carla would stand in your settlement for hours and hours... turns out she was a spy.

Comment: i thought that was weird too, should i kill her?

Comment: I dunno, I find her useful for trading. I don't know if it has any effect on gameplay, seeing as the only thing I've seen is that one terminal.If you like being the fist of justice, sure.

Comment: dont like being fooled much

Comment: were they referring t fallout 3 Lucas Simms?

Comment: I stole from her early in the game before I realized that would mean that I could never trade with her. I later inadvertently killed her. Hasn't had any effect on the game that I know of.

Comment: @Sparta270 Here's a link to the terminal entry in question: [List of Informants](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/The_Institute_terminal_entries#List_of_Informants). Lucas Simms is not on the list. Lucas *Miller* is. Lucas is the roaming armor trader. Doc Weathers and Cricket are on the list as well.

Answer (score -1):

I know this answer is super late but I was busy looking up who the informants were as I forgot, I intend to go on a rampage :-)

BUT I noticed something rather interesting with regards to this. At my Sanctuary there was a spat between two settlers where one was going mental accusing the other of being a synth, I settled the spat with both characters going back to their daily duties (Used some chems to boost my charisma) and I left to go do my routine junk scrap and trade to Trashcan Carla who just so happend to be there as it was all going down.
Well this was before I got to the institute so I was none the wiser but the settler they accused of being a synth just disappeared, at first I thought it was completely random and some sort of bug or glitch but then when I found out about Carla it made logical sense as to what happend to my settler.

Comment: This is not an aswer, though